# Nifi PutHiveStreaming with null timestamp values

Tags: hive, timestamp, apache-nifi

I have the target field type in hive as timestamp and from the source I get the json that has either proper timestamp field or "" or null sometimes. I am converting the source JsonToAvro before using PutHiveStreaming processor. The records with proper timestamp format gets into my hive target table successfully. But those that with ""/null (Empty String set) values show the error - Illegal format. Timestamp format should be" YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fffffffff] ". I know if I can default it to some date when it is null/empty, it works.But I do not want that. I want it to be as null in my target table when it is null. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your Avro schema that is used for creating your table, you can have that field accept `null` by specifying : "fields" : [
    {"name": "insertTime", "type": ["null", "long"]} 
  ]

Comment: I get timestamp field from source in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" and some times "" or null. So, I cannot have the avro schema as "long" type.

Comment: Well then you can make that field accept either `string` or `null` i.e. `"fields" : [ {"name": "insertTime", "type": ["null", "string"]} ]`

Comment: That is exactly what I tried, but it doesn't work when the value is null or "" or for that matter any string that is not in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: Can you share your Avro schema?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..We got around this problem by adjusting the schema before calling puthivestreaming, though I think it was better if puthivestreaming handled empty string values for timestamp fields. Anyways, here is the sample avro schema that am using {
"type": "record",
"name": "Test_Schema",
"fields":[
 {"name" :"id", "type" : ["string","null"]},
 {"name" :"record_date", "type" : ["string","null"]},
 {"name" :"operation", "type" : ["string","null"]}
  ]
}